# Why "<=numeric_limits<int>::max()" is faster than "<numeric_limits<int>::max()"?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am doing [leetcode 322](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/),use `coin <= numeric_limits<int>::max()` instead of `coin < numeric_limits<int>::max()` will reduce 12ms, But I can't figure out why?

64 ms solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int coinChange(vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
        vector<int> dp(amount+1, numeric_limits<int>::max());

        dp[0] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= amount; ++i){
            if(dp[i] != numeric_limits<int>::max())
            for(const auto &coin : coins){
                if(coin <= numeric_limits<int>::max() - i && i + coin <= amount)
                dp[i + coin] = min(dp[i + coin], dp[i] + 1);
            }
        }
        return dp[amount] == numeric_limits<int>::max() ? -1 : dp[amount];
    }
};
```

76ms solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int coinChange(vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
        vector<int> dp(amount+1, numeric_limits<int>::max());

        dp[0] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= amount; ++i){
            if(dp[i] != numeric_limits<int>::max())
            for(const auto &coin : coins){
                if(coin < numeric_limits<int>::max() - i && i + coin <= amount)
                dp[i + coin] = min(dp[i + coin], dp[i] + 1);
            }
        }
        return dp[amount] == numeric_limits<int>::max() ? -1 : dp[amount];
    }
};
```

Comment: A 12 ms difference is likely to be due to random chance.

Comment: Leetcode reported timings have little correlation with actual performance; time of day is a better predictor of the runtime displayed. Rerunning your 2 code samples, the effect was reversed: I got 115 ms and 87 ms. I'd recommend to use your own machine for benchmarking; otherwise, be skeptical of anything below a massive time difference (additive and multiplicative) from a remote internet server you have little information about.

Comment: if you want to microbenchmark code a) do it locally b) use a library that is designed for this (that will run the code many times etc) c) be aware that microbenchmarking is very hard as compilers are increasingly smart about optimizing code (and also random things running on your machine may affect timings, like an antivirus check or anything else)